# Custom MyPositionIcon On Tap Creates A Copy Of Custom MyPositionMarker

Tags: android, google-maps-markers

I am trying to replace `mMpap.SetMyPosition(true);` function with my own. I had some success on it and when my custom image for "My Position Icon" is tapped, it moves camera to current location with my custom marker.

Everything works fine on it except whenever "My Position Icon" is tapped, it leaves a copy of marker to that position and moves to current location with a new marker.

I am fairly new to Android Development and looking for some help.

My code inside `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` is:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myPostionButton);
img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getTheLocation();
    }
});
```

And `getTheLocation()` is:

```
if (location != null) {
    final double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    final double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    final Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(
            new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                    .draggable(true)
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_marker)));

    mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
    mMap.setMinZoomPreference(10.0f);
    mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(20.0f);
    //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 16.0f),4000 , null);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 16.0f));
    mMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraMove() {
            LatLng centerOfMap = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
            marker.setPosition(centerOfMap);
        }
    });
    mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraIdle() {
            LatLng centerOfMap = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
            marker.setPosition(centerOfMap);
            double latitude = centerOfMap.latitude;
            double longitude = centerOfMap.longitude;

            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                String str = addressList.get(0).getAddressLine(0) + ", ";
                str += addressList.get(0).getSubLocality() + ", ";
                str += addressList.get(0).getLocality() + ", ";
                str += addressList.get(0).getCountryCode();

                mFromAddress.setText(str);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)` is:

```
mMap = googleMap;
getTheLocation();
```

Please Help.

Comment: before adding the new marker, clear the map using `mMap.clear();`

Comment: Thanks @Akshay Bhat 'AB'. It worked. If you would answer it below I would accept it.

Comment: No00 problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try any one of the following based on your situation: 
1. **If you have only one marker in map**, before adding the new marker, clear the map using `mMap.clear();`
 
2. **If you have multiple markers** then you have to keep your current marker object as member variable `mMarker`. Then just before adding the new marker you can use `mMarker.remove();`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It was just this line of code I was missing.